# AES_ENCRYPT with MYSQL UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, aes

I am trying to do a basic mysql update but using AES_ENCRYPT - can anyone explain why i'm getting an error message? Below is the query :-

```
UPDATE MailList 
SET Email = AES_ENCRYPT( arandomemail@hotmail.com, 'jkfdsfsaKJjdsf' ) 
WHERE ID =  '138142'
```

I get the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@hotmail.co.uk,'jkaKJjkH87') WHERE MailListID = '138142'' at line 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
UPDATE MailList 
SET Email = AES_ENCRYPT( 'arandomemail@hotmail.com', 'jkfdsfsaKJjdsf' ) 
WHERE ID =  '138142'
```

Answer (score 4):

You forgot the `'` around your mail you want to encrypt.

```
UPDATE MailList 
SET Email = AES_ENCRYPT( 'arandomemail@hotmail.com', 'jkfdsfsaKJjdsf' ) 
WHERE ID =  138142
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the email address, `arandomemail@hotmail.com`, in quotes.

```
UPDATE MailList 
SET Email = AES_ENCRYPT( 'arandomemail@hotmail.com', 'jkfdsfsaKJjdsf' ) 
WHERE ID =  '138142'
```